# Why these circuits always choose the biggest voltage drop way to flow?

Tags: voltage, diodes

I have 2 circuits like below:

[image]

I found that current only flow through the line which has the biggest voltage drop (like in the first circuit, the current only flow through the `D8` diode which connect 3V source to ground).

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D8 cathode voltage is higher than D9 anode and D10 anode. Therefore a small reverse current flows through them as shown.D8 anode is higher than D8 cathode, so current flows in the forward direction through it.

The voltages in the lower diagram are not connected so currents cannot flow.

Comment: But why there are no current flow through D9 and D10 in forward bias? How the higher cathode voltage of D8 can block 2 other lines?

Comment: Current flows from high voltage to low voltage. So D9 and D10 are reverse biased.

Comment: I thought D9 and D10 are also forward bias so the current can flow through them? (example, D9 has 2V at anode and 0V at ground).

Comment: D9 has 2V on the anode and 2.31 V on the cathode. So it is reverse biased

Comment: Ah, I get it, thanks a lot for explaining.

Comment: @Becker what do you think forward-biased and reverse-biased means?

Comment: @user253751 I think forward bias is when anode voltage is bigger than cathode voltage, and reverse bias is when anode voltage is smaller than cathode voltage. But I just wonder how these circuits "know" which voltage at D8(K) is best for them. I mean why the current doesn't flow through D10, make D8(K)=0.3V then blow up D8 and D9?

Comment: @Becker it does, but why would that blow up D8 and D9? Current stops flowing through D10 when D8(K) gets above 0.3V-ish, it stops flowing through D9 when D8(K) gets above 1.3V-ish, and it stops flowing through D8 when D8(K) gets above 2.3V-ish.